# After changing a variable, the next input that's supposed to use the updated variable uses the old one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and Stack overflow so sorry if my question is lacking information, but I hope you can solve it.

To give some background, I am making a game that generates a random alphabet with some words in there (kind of like a word search) and I am unable to remove a specific letter (to make it easier for the user to guess) until after the response has been given. Valid words are the words that are in the alphabet, and random_az_word is a string of a random alphabet.

Here is the code:

```
while not user_win:
user_input = input(input_question)
if user_input in valid_words:
    user_win = True
while not user_input.isalpha():
    user_valid = False
    input_question = 'Please put in a valid word '
    user_input = input(input_question)
if user_input not in valid_words:
    while not remove:
        remove_num = random.randint(1,int(len(random_az_word)-1))
        if random_az_word[remove_num] not in ''.join(valid_words):
            remove = True
    random_az_word = random_az_word.replace(random_az_word[remove_num],'')
    input_question = f'Incorrect, please try again, after removing the letter {random_az_word[remove_num]} alphabet is {random_az_word} '
```

After wards, the input question ends up with the old alphabet (without the removed letter), until after you put in a response.

PS. I'm very tired right now so I could just be missing a very noticeable mistake, I apologize if that's the case.

Comment: Can you show a complete example of your code? Multiple variables aren't defined in the what you've shown, especially `random_az_word` and `valid_words`.

Comment: Also can see an indentation issue. Can you format the code as in your actual implementation.